# How to run custom php code when a new user registers on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i run custom php code when a new user registers on wordpress?

Im trying to send a sms to the admin once a new user registers. I know how to send the sms, just unsure where to put the code.

I've got php snippets installed.

Comment: This should help: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `user_register` action hook that fires immediately after a new user is registered.

```
function myfunction_after_registration( $user_id ) {
    // send your SMS to the admin about $user_id
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'myfunction_after_registration', 10, 1 );
```

I would add this in `functions.php`, not sure about the "php snippets" you are referring to.

[Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/)

Comment: You also need another hook if it's multisite. I don't have it in front of me, I'll dig it up. (It has a hard-to-guess name.)

Comment: @O.Jones you are talking about this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wpmu_new_user/

Comment: So you'd think, @GeorgeP. But that hook fires before the new user is associated with any "blog" (subsite number). Another event fires when the user is associated with a blog.

Comment: You are adding specs of your own to the question. OP asked about sending an SMS, to the admin and the above hooks will solve his problem.